# JPA 2.0 Pessimistic Lock Testing Way

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

Although I learned and reference `JPA 2.0 pessimistic lock`,

- I don't know where is it used and how can I test it?
- What is the best way to test it without using web client?
- What will be best example?

Answer (score 0):

See [Locking and Concurrency in Java Persistence 2.0](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/locking_and_concurrency_in_java)

*Pessimistic locking assumes that transactions will frequently collide. In pessimistic locking, a transaction that reads the data locks it. Another transaction cannot change the data until the first transaction commits the read.*

So if you use pessimistic lock you block entire entity (at least row) and nobody else can read/write in the same time.

Comment: How can I test it? Could you provide the way to test?

Comment: You should lock PESSIMISTIC_READ in one thread and wait (Thread.sleep), and in second open new transaction and try to change the entity.